# How does an Indian citizen with German national visa return back to anywhere in the EU?

Tags: schengen, germany, europe, covid-19, long-stay-visas

I have a German national visa (got through the work, although not working there anymore). Visa is still valid for 1 more year.

I want to get back to the EU (anywhere in the EU). But it seems like every country has a restriction for people coming outside of EU. But once you are in the EU, they allow you to travel kind of freely.

I checked the German rules. I didn't understand it correctly, but they said you need some letter from the employer that you are an essential worker (?) which I can't provide.

So what are alternative options for me to get back into the Schengen zone?

Comment: Where do you reside?

Comment: @phoog India currently.

Comment: What German rules were you checking?

Comment: And if you still reside in India, how is it that you are "returning" to Europe?

Comment: @phoog Because I moved to India since coronavirus started?

Comment: @VarunAgw Is your German visa still valid if you are no longer in employment in Germany? Did you/your employer inform the relevant Foreigners Authority of your change of circumstances?

Comment: Did you give up your apartment in Germany?  If you formerly resided there then your strongest approach is likely to be establishing that you are a resident and that your recent extended absence, in light of the circumstances, should not be taken as interrupting your residence.  This may be possible even if you gave up your apartment, though it seems like it might be a long shot.

Comment: @phoog Yes. I don't have an apartment there.

Comment: Right now you should also check what restrictions there are for anyone (including German citizens) arriving in Germany from India due to Covid. For example having to self-isolate for 14 days. I have no idea _if_ there are restrictions, but it's definitely something you need to check.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php, you can enter Germany because of an exception applying to "passengers with a long term visa issued by an EEA Member State or Switzerland."

While airlines will check IATA (Timatic, more specifically), it's prudent to check the official source which concurs. https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/faqs/EN/topics/civil-protection/coronavirus/travel-restrictions-border-control/travel-restriction-border-control-list.html#f14104798

> EU citizens and nationals of the United Kingdom, Liechtenstein, Switzerland, Norway and Iceland and the members of their immediate family (spouse, unmarried minor children, parents of minors) are exempted from the travel restrictions.
> The same applies to third-country nationals who already have a longer-term right of residence in an EU member state

Comment: I actually saw the official Germany website earlier but it didn't mention any such thing [Link1](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/einreiseundaufenthalt/coronavirus#content_0) [Link2](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/faqs/EN/topics/civil-protection/coronavirus/travel-restrictions-border-control/travel-restriction-border-control-list.html#f14104798)

Comment: So what do you suggest? Will you trust IATA over official website?

Comment: @VarunAgw I suggest you read "What restrictions apply to air and sea travel outside of the European Union?" on Link2. The answer is there and concurs with IATA.

Comment: @chx, this is more than just an edit and should have been a separate answer. (You know that some people do not like any edits, so keep your small as well.)

Comment: @Willeke It's the same answer ("EEA residents are welcome"), just with a second source -- VarunAgw asked for a more official source and actually they provided one, I just copied the link from the comment and made it a no-link-only edit.

Comment: This answer assumes that the residence permit has not expired. In general a residence permit will expire after an absence of 6 months **or** the absence is not temporary in nature (deregistration of residence). [§51 (1)(6,7) AufthG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p1053)

Comment: @VarunAgw Your second link contains a portion relevent to your situation: **Return to habitual abode**. If you have an exit stamp that is older than 6 months, the border guard may consider the residence permit as expired (the residence has been *abandoned*).

Comment: @MarkJohnson the question states that it is a visa, not a residence permit, and the statute you've linked to says "a visa issued for multiple entries or valid for more than 90 days does not expire pursuant to no. 6 or 7."

Comment: A national d-visa, that allows someone to work, are generally only issued (and not coverted into a residence permit) when the work contract is restricted in time up to 1 year. The visa Handbuch (V. Ausstellung von D-Visa, page 27) states: *The maximum period of validity of twelve months may not be exceeded under any circumstances*. So lets assume the OP has used the incorrect terminology since he states its still valid for more than one year.